# Magnet size vs field strength

Tags: magnetic-fields, geomagnetism

Why is a compass not significantly affected by nearby (less than a couple meters) powerful magnets (such as those located inside home appliances and electronics) given Earth's magnetic field is just about 0.65 Gauss?

Comment: An intuitive way to look at it is simply: the Earth is HUGE and the dishwasher is TINY.

Answer (score 0):

[This World Health Organisarion page](https://www.who.int/peh-emf/about/WhatisEMF/en/index3.html) gives a table of typical magnetic flux densities at a range of distances from various household appliances.

For unit conversion, $100 \space \mu$Tesla is $1$ Gauss.

Bottom line is you have to be within a few centimetres of something with an electric motor such as a vacuum cleaner or a hair dryer before the magnetic flux density is greater than the earth’s geomagnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic dipole fields decrease rapidly with distance (as 1/$r^3$ at a larger distance r).  Never the less, on a boat, one needs to keep ferromagnetic materials and electrical devices away from the compass used for navigation.